# Flipping rectangle bits

Tags: algorithm

Flip the world is a game. In this game a matrix of size N*M is given, which consists of numbers. Each number can be 1 or 0 only. The rows are numbered from 1 to N, and the columns are numbered from 1 to M.

Following steps can be called as a single move.

Select two integers x,y (1<=x<=N and 1<=y<=M) i.e. one square on the matrix.

All the integers in the rectangle denoted by (1,1) and (x,y) i.e. rectangle having top-left and bottom-right points as (1,1) and (x,y) are toggled(1 is made 0 and 0 is made 1).

For example, in this matrix (N=4 and M=3)

```
101
110
101
000
```

if we choose x=3 and y=2, the new state of matrix would be

```
011
000
011
000
```

For a given state of matrix, aim of the game is to reduce the matrix to a state where all numbers are 1. What is minimum number of moves required.

How to solve this problem?

This is not a homework problem.I'm pretty confused with it.I'm fighting with this problem for past two days.And maintaining a 2-D array for number of ones and zeros.
I tried like balancing the number of one's and number of zeroes.But didn't work out.Any hints or solutions. ?

Source: [Hackerearth](http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/flip-the-world)

Answer (score 0):

Hint #1: Use a greedy approach from bottom to top. That is: if the cell (n, m) is 0 then you must apply XOR to the rectangle (0,0)-(n,m). So try traversing all cells from bottom to top and from right to left and if the current cell is zero then perform a move on it.

This yields a O(n^4) solution.

To get a n^2 solution use, for example, accumulated sums in every rectangle.